# Objective C - hide tabs bar according to some action

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a navigation bar and a tabs bar below it, I want to hide it when some action happens, here is my method:

```
    BOOL isHidden = YES;
- (NSInteger)numberOfViewControllers {
    return self.names.count +1;
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return vc;
}

- (NSString *)titleForTabAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    if (index == 0) {
        return (@"All");
    }
    return [[self.names objectAtIndex:index-1]Name];

}
```

- The bar I want to hide is "Sub Title" only not the "Header" as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: header is your navigation bar correct, if yes can you show the gesture or button action for action

Comment: Detail the code where you are adding the navigation bar

Comment: yes header is my navigation bar and Sub title is my tabs bar that I want to hide

Comment: I added the methods

Comment: Have you tried [tabbar setHidden:] ?

Comment: yes, I solved the problem now thanks